# Angular form showing html content

Tags: angular, formgroups

Hi i am new for angular I wrote below code for display **name** and **session** in card but I see result as below can some one help me what is my mistake?

### Code

```
<div class="card">
  <form [formGroup]="userForm">
    <div class="mt-5">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
              <input="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Session</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
              <input="text" formControlName="session" class="form-control" placeholder="Session">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `type` attribute in your input tag.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` tag is part of HTML and nothing to do with angular. You are using incorrect syntax and angular shows it as a string. There are multiple attributes that can be taken by `input` for more details check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) (you were missing type attribute).

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**You don't have the type attribute in your input tag.**


<div class="card">
  <form >
    <div class="mt-5">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Session</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Session">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some description to the code, it helps other user to understand it correctly.

Comment: You written:-

<input="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">

that is wrong you have to write input type="text" instead of input="text"

<input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">